# Struggling with FOR or WHILE loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, computer-science

I am new to programming and am confused as to how to go about making my code print multiple times. Can someone help me with the program?

```
/**Description: Write a program to compute the yearly depreciation for an item whose
 purchase price, salvage value, and expected years of service are entered by the user. 
 Construct the program     so it will run four times before it terminates*/
```

After this, i don't know how what to do to get the program to print multiple times.

```
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {

BufferedReader userin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inputData;

        double price;
        double salvageValue; 
        int years;

        System.out.println("Run #1");
        System.out.print("Enter Price ");
        inputData = userin.readLine();
        price = Double.parseDouble( inputData );
        System.out.print("Enter Salvage Value ");
        inputData = userin.readLine();
        salvageValue = Double.parseDouble( inputData );
        System.out.print("Enter Estimated Life in years ");
        inputData = userin.readLine();
        years = Integer.parseInt( inputData );
        double depreciation = (price - salvageValue) / years;
        double depreciationRounded = Math.round(depreciation * 100.0) / 100.0;
        System.out.println("Annual Depreciation " + depreciationRounded + "\n");
    }
}

/*Sample Output:

Run #1

Enter Price 250.00

Enter Salvage Value 35.00

Enter Estimated Life in years 8

Annual Depreciation 26.88
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to iterate 4 times.... so simply encapsulate the logic in a for loop

```
for(int counter=0; counter< 4; counter++) {
   // logic goes here
}
```

How this works:

Step 1:  When the for loop is encountered initially, the first section of the 3 code sections inside the for loop is run and if you declare a variable here it's scope is only within the loop.

Step 2:  The 2nd section of the for loop code is run and evaluates to "true" or "false" if it evaluates to false the for loop is exited.

Step 3:  The code within the for loop is executed with the variable (int this counter) available if needed within the loop (in your case I don't think you need the variable in the loop just to enforce 4 iterations)

Step 4:  The 3rd section of the for loop code is run.

Step 5:  Repeat steps 2-5 until step 2 evaluates to false

Hope that helps.

Comment: It helps a lot more understanding how it works than it does just seeing it. So thank you for explaining everything.

Answer (score 0):

look at this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

        BufferedReader userin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inputData;

        double price;
        double salvageValue;
        int years;

        System.out.println("Run #" + i);
        System.out.print("Enter Price ");
        try {
            inputData = userin.readLine();
            price = Double.parseDouble(inputData);
            System.out.print("Enter Salvage Value ");
            inputData = userin.readLine();
            salvageValue = Double.parseDouble(inputData);
            System.out.print("Enter Estimated Life in years ");
            inputData = userin.readLine();
            years = Integer.parseInt(inputData);
            double depreciation = (price - salvageValue) / years;
            double depreciationRounded = Math.round(depreciation * 100.0) / 100.0;
            System.out.println("Annual Depreciation " + depreciationRounded + "\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("program termination");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Is it helpful?

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps a lot. I only started programming last month and loops are fairly new to me, so thank you for the explanation, it helped me understand for-loops much better.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to do the following:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader userin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inputData;

        double price;
        double salvageValue;
        int years;

        int numberOfSteps = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSteps; i++) {

            System.out.println("Run #"+i);
            System.out.print("Enter Price ");
            inputData = userin.readLine();
            price = Double.parseDouble(inputData);
            System.out.print("Enter Salvage Value ");
            inputData = userin.readLine();
            salvageValue = Double.parseDouble(inputData);
            System.out.print("Enter Estimated Life in years ");
            inputData = userin.readLine();
            years = Integer.parseInt(inputData);
            double depreciation = (price - salvageValue) / years;
            double depreciationRounded = Math.round(depreciation * 100.0) / 100.0;
            System.out.println("Annual Depreciation " + depreciationRounded
                    + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps,

Clemencio Morales Lucas.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a visual learner, so it helps to see how to do it, for me to better understand the concepts of looping. Thank you for the help.